# chatting/video calling app using Openfire 4.0.1

Tags: open-source, audio, chat, video-conferencing, office

I am looking for a multi platform program (majorly win 7), which i can run using **Openfire 4.0.1** server for the following uses:

1. Instant Messaging
2. Audio calling
3. Video calling
4. User online or offline status display
5. Multiplatform support
6. **It Should be FREE**

I have already installed openfire 4.0.1 server and now i want a application that can use this openfire server.

Thanks in advance.